# Quarkus Quinoa UI Dir Outside of Project

Tags: quarkus

I am using Quarkus and Quinoa to serve my Angular application. Quinoa specifies that I can configure the Web UI directory to be outside the Quarkus project.

My project structure looks like this:

```
- frontend [Angular Project]
- hello-world [Quarkus Project]
```

Inside the application properties I specify the quinoa properties:

```
quarkus.quinoa.ui-dir=../../frontend
quarkus.quinoa.dev-server.port=4200
quarkus.quinoa.enable-spa-routing=true
quarkus.quinoa.frozen-lockfile=true
```

As you can see, I am setting the frontend path relative to the project root. However, when I am trying to run the application `quarkus dev`, it is giving me the following error:

```
Quinoa directory not found 'quarkus.quinoa.ui-dir=../../frontend'
```

When I am placing the frontend inside the quarkus project with the ui dir pointing to the changed path, it works as expected.

Why does it not work with my frontend folder being outside of the quarkus project directory and how would could I make it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at your directory structure it seems the correct config should be:

```
quarkus.quinoa.ui-dir=../frontend
```

As described in the doc the ui-dir is relative to the project-root:

https://quarkiverse.github.io/quarkiverse-docs/quarkus-quinoa/dev/index.html#quarkus-quinoa_quarkus.quinoa.ui-dir

You could also used an absolute path but that would make it incompatible with other machines and team members.

I've created an issue on Quinoa, because I find the error log could be better:
https://github.com/quarkiverse/quarkus-quinoa/issues/282